# New website ranking problem

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

I have a 2 week old blog with 10 articles. Submitted to google search console and sitemap is also submitted. Used yoast seo plugin and on page optimization is good.

**The problem**

When I type one of my blog headline (it's unique) in google and search, my blog isn't appearing in any page of google search result.

Why is that?

Comment: Is the domain new? or you Bought it from some one else or was a expired domain?

Comment: Domain is new. Not an expired or bought from someone else.

Comment: Paul asked some pertinent questions, and we would have to ask quite a few more since there's not that much to go off of. The linked questions however should help you identify what the issue(s) is. Most likely Google just hasn't gotten around to indexing it yet since it's a new domain. Be sure to sign up for [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome), and use the Fetch as Google tool there to see if there's any issues with crawling your site. That also might help to trigger indexing it as well.

Comment: Your site is simply too new. It will take months to begin ranking as it should. Do not drive yourself crazy looking at search performance for quite a while. Take this time and focus on adding content to your site and improving internal linking to encourage users to stick around. Google likes sites that adds content and improves content periodically, it does not have to be at a rapid pace. Just go at whatever pace is right for you. Also, take this time to build any social media presence you can. That too will take time, however, beginning the outreach sooner does help. Cheers!!